# Elasticsearch specify routing in Hive

Tags: elasticsearch

Assume I have an ElasticSearch Mapping as follows

`{"mappings":
     {"post":
     {"_routing": {"required": true, "path": "user_id"},
    "properties": {
     "user_id": {"type": "integer"},
     username": {"type": "string"},
     "text": {"type": "string"}}}}}`

How do I represent the routing via Hive table?
I know there is a property called es.mapping.routing.
So do I say es.mapping.routing='user_id'?
I tried that but it did not work.
Can someone list out the syntax?

Thanks